# Java Date Format Requsit?

Tags: oracle, jdbc

Spec : Java 1.7
Db   : Oracle 11g

Assertion :

Using Toad, for an Sql query, data of a certain Date is as follows

```
CREATE_DATE : TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE
```

The date Displayed from the CREATE_DATE is 30-JUN-10 05.04.58.441751000 AM -05:00

Question :

What format needs to be used so as use JDBC and parse the TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE to fetch as convert to another fomat "dd-mm-yy' ?

Comment: Are you trying to do the conversion in Oracle or in Java?

Comment: You use `getTimestamp` and apply a date format in Java code...

Comment: I am using the ResultSet.getTimestamp()...further i need to convert the Result set to 'dd-mm-yy' format, hence trying to use SimpleDateFormat...but this needs the '30-JUN-10 05.04.58.441751000 AM -05:00' format to parse and conver to required o/p ?